# Pyinstaller error: 'SystemError: codesign failure!' on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I have made an application that I am now distributing on macos and windows (windows successfully compiled) but when I try to compile my app it keeps throwing the error ***SystemError: codesign failure!*** In pyinstaller I am using the *--onefile* flag, and I have tried it without the flag (`python pyinstaller.py app.py`, I could not use `python pyinstaller app.py` as I was thrown *command not found*). This is the full error message:

```
326 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
4245 WARNING: codesign command (['codesign', '-s', '-', '--force', '--all-architectures', '--timestamp', '/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller/bincache00_py39_64bit/x86_64/adhoc/no-entitlements/lib-dynload/resource.cpython-39-darwin.so']) failed with error code 1!
stdout: ''
stderr: '/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/pyinstaller/bincache00_py39_64bit/x86_64/adhoc/no-entitlements/lib-dynload/resource.cpython-39-darwin.so: invalid or unsupported format for signature\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Cloud/hero/pyinstaller.py", line 17, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Cloud/hero/app.spec", line 23, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 509, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(self.toc, cdict=kwargs.get('cdict', None),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 274, in assemble
    fnm = checkCache(fnm, strip=self.strip_binaries,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/utils.py", line 391, in checkCache
    osxutils.sign_binary(cachedfile, codesign_identity, entitlements_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 383, in sign_binary
    raise SystemError("codesign failure!")
SystemError: codesign failure!
```

Since I have never compiled an app for mac and this is my first time doing it, I have no idea what this really means. This is using python 3.9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the way pyinstaller performs ad-hoc signing since codesigning changed sometime after 4.3 (see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6167). Building on the latest Big Sur (MacOS 11.5.2) should work fine but I assume you're on Catalina or earlier.

You can either:

- Downgrade to pyinstaller 4.3 with `pip uninstall pyinstaller` and `pip install -Iv pyinstaller==4.3` and then rebuild as you were.

or

- Provide a certificate to sign the app yourself.

If you want to sign the app yourself you can do so like so:

1. Open `Keychain Access`
2. Go to the menu at the top of the screen and select `Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate`
3. In the window that appears change `Certificate Type` to `Code Signing` ,  select `Create` and note the name of the certificate
4. Build your `pyinstaller` source with the `--codesign-identity <name>` flag where `<name>` is the name of the certificate you created in step 3.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Lachlan. This did work for me, however, partially. I was able to generate an executable. However, I have a CI/CD build going on in Travis CI that generates the executable. Your final executable isn't going to be signed and you have to configure your CI/CD pipeline to automate the job of signing this executable. Because you won't be able to distribute it otherwise. At least that executable won't run on Big Sur...

Comment: FWIW I was able to build and run an app using Pyinstaller 5.0.dev0 with --onefile and --windowed args on MacOS 12.1 without signing the app myself. I did have a problem with codesigning when trying to perform the build on a network drive, but once copied to my Mac it ran correctly