# The executable I'm creating with Pyinstaller works only on my device even I'm creating a certificate (MacOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm a python's beginner, I wrote a program and I tried to transform it to an executable, so I used Pyinstaller and everything worked until I tried to share my app to the other MacOS devices, it doesn't want to work, so when I tried this solution from this guy's problem :

[Pyinstaller error: 'SystemError: codesign failure!' on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884906/pyinstaller-error-systemerror-codesign-failure-on-macos)

that seems someway he have the same issue, so I created a certificate and trying this command in terminal:

`pyinstaller --windowed --osx-entitlements-file Info.plist --codesign-identity Ahmed --add-data="fichier référence des prix.xlsx:." --add-data="Réf_productible1.csv:." --add-data="courbe1.xlsx:." app12.py`

but this time I can't even open it in my device showing the following message:

[It means impossible to open the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q57FS.png)

And the terminal was like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVBVq.png)

the file 'Info.plist' contain the following code :

I add that am really beginner on IT and python so I'm learning everyday.

`

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.goe.lorient.app12</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>app12</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`

Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your plist is missing something about an entitlement that is needed - like do you access a camera or file space? You need to add that to your entitlements.

Also you could try codesign separately on your mac from terminal:

```
codesign -s <identity> <absolute-bundle-path>
```

Here is an example plist file that you could modify and try to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>...displayname</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>...filename</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon-windowed.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>...identifier</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>...bundlename</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.0</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```